# Make parent method return type matching its derivated class type

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, derived-class

I have a parent class like this:

```
public class WebserviceResultPerNode 
{
    public List<DBMappingResult> mapTable { get; set; }

    public static WebserviceResultPerNode newInstanceFromError(ErrorResponse error)
    {
        return new WebserviceResultPerNode
        {
            mapTable = null,
            responseCode = error.responseCode,
            responseMessage = error.responseMessage
        };
    }
}
```

It have some derived classes such as below:

```
public class WebserviceInsertResultPerNode : WebserviceResultPerNode
{
}
```

Now I want to make derived classes like `WebserviceInsertResultPerNode` such that when I call `WebserviceInsertResultPerNode.newInstanceFromError()` their return type be same as derived class not parent class. Currently return type of `newInstanceFromError` is type of parent class, i.e. `WebserviceResultPerNode`.
I want to know are there any ways to override `WebserviceInsertResultPerNode.newInstanceFromError` such that its return type be `WebserviceInsertResultPerNode` but I don't need to initialize fields of parent class without the need to rewrite them.

How can I rewrite my code to achieve this goal?

Comment: Do `Base b = new Derived();`. but parent's constructor will be called before the derived class

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this by using reflection, providing child classes will always have a parameter-less constructor:

```
public class WebserviceResultPerNode<T> where T : WebserviceResultPerNode<T>, new()
{
    public static T NewInstanceFromError(ErrorResponse error)
    {
        return new T() { … };
    };
}
```

Then the descendant class will look like this:

```
public class MyWebServiceResult : WebserviceResultPerNode<MyWebServiceResult> { … }
```

However, I do strongly recommend decomposing the [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) into a separate factory class for the sake of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: This bit of code is a bit complicated for me since I don't know anything about reflection. However it seems pretty small and clean :)

Comment: Besides I saw many people talk about separation of concerns. Do you know any references in context of software development? I saw many design patterns and architectures but I don't know a reference which compared them and talked about its philosophy

Comment: It's not refleciton, it's generics. Note that it has its disadvantages, e.g. it's not easy to use such a parent class in all scenarios without providing an actual type argument or making the surrounding code generic, too. Hence I'd really advice you read about the factory pattern and make a separate factory class.